# Quickly iterate over the list and wait for a response

Tags: c#

I have a large database with a list of site URLs that need to be processed. Faced the problem that it takes a very long time.
I haven't written anything in C # for a long time, I've forgotten it.
Tell me, is it really possible to make my while quickly go through the file, collect and send each line for processing.
I will explain. File - 5m links. Run while - he quickly read all lines and asynchronously made 5m httpwebrequest requests. You just have to wait.
If not, how can this be accelerated?

Start function: `startSearch();`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace URLParser
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label5.AutoSize = false;
            label5.Height = 2;
            label5.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            label5.Width = ClientRectangle.Width;

            textBox2.Text = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            textBox3.Text = "FilenameExample";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Title = "Text file";
            ofd.Filter = "URL list (*.txt)|*.txt";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;
            }
        }

        private async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await startSearch();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
            {
                if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    textBox2.Text = dialog.SelectedPath;
                }
            }
        }

        public int count;
        public async Task startSearch()
        {
            var csv = new StringBuilder();
            string outPath = textBox2.Text;
            string outName = textBox3.Text;
            count = 0;
            string fileName = textBox1.Text;
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                const Int32 BufferSize = 128;
                using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, BufferSize))
                {
                    String line;
                    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        var r = await cURL(line.Trim());
                        if(r != null)
                        {
                            using (var tw = new StreamWriter(outPath + "\\" + outName + ".csv", true))
                            {
                                tw.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", r));
                            }
                        }
                        textBox4.Text = count.ToString();
                        count++;
                        //break;
                    }
                }
            } else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File not exist", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        public async Task<string[]> cURL(string url)
        {
            String[] responseText = await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                string startURL = "", statusGet = "", respURL = "", getCMS = "", emailList = "";

                if (!url.Contains("http"))
                {
                    url = "http://" + url;
                }

                try
                {
                    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                    httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                    httpWebRequest.Date = DateTime.Now.Date;
                    httpWebRequest.Timeout = 4000;
                    httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36";
                    string requestResult = null;
                    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                    int status = (int)httpResponse.StatusCode;
                    if (status == 200)
                    {
                        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            requestResult = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                            string respUrl = httpResponse.ResponseUri.ToString();

                            HashSet<string> emails = new HashSet<string>();
                            Regex ItemRegex = new Regex(@"[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.((?!.*png|.*jpg)[a-z]{2,10})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?", RegexOptions.Compiled);
                            foreach (Match ItemMatch in ItemRegex.Matches(requestResult))
                            {
                                emails.Add(ItemMatch.ToString());
                            }

                            startURL = url;
                            statusGet = status.ToString();
                            respURL = respUrl;
                            getCMS = GetCMS(requestResult);
                            emailList = String.Join(";", emails);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch { }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(statusGet) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(respURL))
                {
                    return new[] { startURL, statusGet, respURL, getCMS, emailList };
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            });

            return responseText;
        }

        public string GetCMS(string html)
        {
            if(html.Contains(@"src=""/bitrix/") && html.Contains(@"<link href=""/bitrix")) {
                return "Bitrix";
            } else if(html.Contains(@"<meta name=""modxru""")) {
                return "Modx";
            } else if(html.Contains(@"idontknowhowtofindthiscms:D")) {
                //return "October-CMS";
            } else if(html.Contains(@"/netcat_files/") && html.Contains(@"<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""/netcat")) {
                return "Netcat";
            } else if(html.Contains(@"<img src=""/phpshop") && html.Contains(@"<script src=""/phpshop")) {
                return "PhpShop";
            } else if(html.Contains(@"<script type=""text/x-magento-init") && html.Contains(@"Magento_Ui/")) {
                return "Magento";
            } else if(html.Contains(@"/wa-data/public")) {
                return "Shop-Script";
            } else if(html.Contains(@"catalog/view/theme")) {
                return "OpenCart";
            } else if(html.Contains(@"data-drupal-")) {
                return "Drupal";
            } else if(html.Contains(@"/wp-content/")) {
                return "Wordpress";
            } else if(html.Contains(@"<meta name=""generator"" content=""Joomla")) {
                return "Joomla";
            } else if(html.Contains(@"var dle_admin")) {
                return "DataLife Engine";
            }
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [`HttpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) documentation:

> We don't recommend that you use `HttpWebRequest` for new development. Instead, use the [`System.Net.Http.HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) class.

Also `HttpClient` fluently and by default reusing the connections and has `async` API out-of-the-box.

Here's an example with `HttpClient` and some additional tweaks. Only changed methods:

```csharp
// HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use.
private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...existing code...

    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10; // this line is not needed in .NET Core
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.ParseAdd("keep-alive");
    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);
}

// rewritten method
public async Task<string[]> cURL(string url, SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
{
    try
    {
        if (!url.StartsWith("http")) url = "http://" + url;

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string statusGet = ((int)response.StatusCode).ToString();
                string respURL = response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString();

                string requestResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                HashSet<string> emails = new HashSet<string>();
                Regex ItemRegex = new Regex(@"[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.((?!.*png|.*jpg)[a-z]{2,10})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?", RegexOptions.Compiled);
                foreach (Match ItemMatch in ItemRegex.Matches(requestResult))
                {
                    emails.Add(ItemMatch.ToString());
                }
                string getCMS = GetCMS(requestResult);
                string emailList = string.Join(";", emails);

                return new[] { url, statusGet, respURL, getCMS, emailList };
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

This code must be faster than existing one.

For more performance boost need adding some concurrency for `startSearch()`:

```csharp
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, BufferSize))
using (SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(Environment.ProcessorCount * 2))
{
    List<Task<string[]>> tasks = new List<Task<string[]>>();
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        tasks.Add(cURL(sr.ReadLine().Trim(), semaphore));
        if (tasks.Count == 1000 || sr.EndOfStream) // flush results
        {
            string[][] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outPath + "\\" + outName + ".csv", true))
            {
                foreach (string[] r in results)
                {
                    if (r != null) sw.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", r));
                }
            }
            tasks.Clear();
        }
        textBox4.Text = count.ToString();
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have some error on this line: `Task<string[]> tasks = new Task<string[]>();`
0 arguments after =

Comment: @ScreamX sorry, fixed.

Comment: After some time working with this script, I noticed one problem. Sometimes the process stops at 999 or 3999 or 10999 and does not continue. What could this be connected with, not in the know? There are no errors.

Comment: @ScreamX Script terminates or hangs? Try wrapping the parent script with `try-catch`. There's may be some `Exception` but you don't see it.

Comment: `Error: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: Task canceled.
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult ()`

Comment: @ScreamX it may happen if you close the app while tasks are running. I see no other reasons for that here, sorry. But if it happens inside `cURL` method, you may possibly ignore it, it's not unhandled.